# How to Add Randomness in Discord.py

Tags: python, random, discord.py

I am new to Python, I need help adding randomness into my bot on Discord. I made a command where there was a 0.01% chance of getting a message. However only the else statement worked, if the rare chance happened, no message was sent to the channel.

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
@commands.has_role("Member")
async def addrole(ctx):
    if random.randint(1, 10000) < 2:
        await ctx.channel.send("wow rare")

    else:
        await ctx.channel.send("not cool")
```

Comment: I also imported random and discord, sorry for not including it in the code.

Comment: I have honestly no idea what you're asking about, would you mind clearing up some things? What's your question here exactly? Also in the code you're showing us, the chances are `0.0001%` not `0.01%`.

Comment: how will you know that it's the rare chance and that it's the bot not working properly and not just the event not occurring even if the 1/1000 event did occur?

Comment: i changed the 2 into 9999, however, it does not send "wow rare", I am asking how to make the rare chance to work and actually send "wow rare", sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if random.randrange(1, 10000) < 2:
```

Try this